# Redirect from login page to other page (on the basis of User Name)

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have login page where each user redirect to same page after successfully login. But I want that redirect page should be  based on username. For example If Manager login, then it should redirect to manager landing page after login and when it login to staff page then it should redirect to staff . Here is my code og login page which direct to all user on same page

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
 
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Password is not valid, display a generic error message
                            $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Username doesn't exist, display a generic error message
                    $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<header><center> <img src = "logo.png" height = "100" width = "180"></center></header>
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card mt-5">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #3fbbc0;">
                        <h4>Login</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">

        <?php 
        if(!empty($login_err)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
        }        
        ?>


        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
<div class="col-md-4">
                <label></label>
             
            </div>    
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
                <label></label>
               <label></label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <center> <input type="submit"  style="background-color: #3fbbc0;" value="Login">
            </div>
         
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

> 

Comment: If the content of the page is different, because the user is different, it could be the same URL for all users, with content that is determined by the user that logged in.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? At the most basic level, use some `if` statements.  More realistically, maybe there is a naming-based convention you could employ, or perhaps storing the name in a database entry would make sense. Or maybe KIKO is right and you don't really need separate pages at all. We need more context and detail before we can give you a clear answer.

Comment: yes login details user name password stor in mysql table. I reaaly need separate pages bec both the user have totally different roles.

Comment: OK. So just add another database column to store the name of the file they should be redirected to.

Comment: how ? let me share my current login script by editing my question. please review it and suggest

Comment: You want to know how to add a column to a database table?

Comment: not a tall, i knew about it, i am asking about script of php

Comment: Well, select that extra column in the database in your sql SELECT query, php can then bind it to a variable, and then you can use that variable with your Location header. None of that is anything new that you haven't done before in your code, it's just one extra field.

Comment: @ADyson $sql = "SELECT user_redirect_uri FROM users WHERE username = ? AND user_password = ?";  and  header('Location: $url'); but nothing is happened

Comment: Well, you seem to have missed the bit where you execute the query, and define $url . Also you don't need a separate query for this, just put that field into the SELECT statement you've already got

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT id, username, password, user_redirect_uri FROM users WHERE username = ?";` ... `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,  $id, $username, $hashed_password, $url);` ...`header('Location: $url'); `

Comment: still the same issue. i dont knew whats wrong in code

Answer (score 1):

User validation is a use case; I assume you already have this logic coded. Another aspect is determining the URL to which the user should be redirected.

To achieve this, you should define a property in the User entity of your database, which you could name "user_redirect_uri." After validating the user during login, you will subsequently need to retrieve the URL for the user's redirection. Your SQL query should look something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_redirect_uri FROM users WHERE username = ? AND user_password = ?";
```

For security reasons, always make sure that the number of returned records is "1". If there are more records, you might be facing a potential SQL injection case.

For security reasons, it's not necessary to retrieve both the password from your SQL query. This could create a vulnerability that malicious users might exploit. Let the user validation be handled by the SQL query.

Considering that you most likely have stored and encoded the user's password in your database, it's advisable to encode the password that comes in the request and directly perform the database query with that value.

To perform a URL redirection, you can achieve it with a simple code snippet like the following:

```
header('Location: $url');
exit;
```

In this case, the variable $url should be fetched from your database.

Comment: sir! i tried this in my code  $sql = "SELECT user_redirect_uri FROM users WHERE username = ? AND user_password = ?"; and header('Location: $url'); but nothing is happened